# OpenCV - PiCamera or cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Tags: opencv, picamera

Quick question, I am starting to work on some Computer Vision programs using my Raspberry Pi 3.
I thought when using the PiCamera you needed to use the specific PiCamera commands however I have simply used cv2.VideoCapture(0) and it opens and accesses the Pi Camera anyway.

What I am finding though is a massive difference between running the same programs (face detection) on my Mac compared to my Pi 3. On the Pi3 there is loads of lag.

So - should I be using the PiCamera commands to capture video, or cv2.VideoCapture(0) and how do I increase the performance?

Thanks

Comment: Is it really surprising that your Mac outperforms your RPi? Is there a performance benchmark you are using to set your expectations wrt the lag?